# What are the odometry msg type in ROS SLAM?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are building a three wheel holonomic motion system. Is there a standard way to publish odometer values? How odometer values are present in gmapping package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298397/what-are-the-odometry-msg-type-in-ros-slam?/) by [Ricco](https://answers.ros.org/users/36622/ricco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-07-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hypomania](https://answers.ros.org/users/36123/hypomania/) on 2018-07-24**:
Could you link the stack/package you are looking at?

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-07-24**:
Is [this](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) what you're looking for?

**Comment by [Ricco](https://answers.ros.org/users/36622/ricco/) on 2018-07-24**:
Actually I'm looking for how to acquire odometer data from motor encoders. I need to know what exactly I have to publish from encoders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The odometry information should be published by the ROS driver for your mobile robot base. Usually, the robot sends encoder ticks via serial or whatever, and the ROS driver then computes the odometry message (i.e., pose and twist; see the link by @stevejp). The formula how to compute the ROS odometry message from encoder ticks depends on your kinematics.

#### Example 1: Generic differential drive platform

https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/f5dc6f2c31cfc76419f073c54a14ab04394ab919/diff_drive_controller/src/odometry.cpp

#### Example 2: PR2 robot (four-wheeled holonomic robot)

https://github.com/PR2/pr2_controllers/blob/f5ad5f6b821ba2aab073703dcabc4c104cd86112/pr2_mechanism_controllers/src/pr2_odometry.cpp

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2018-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ricco](https://answers.ros.org/users/36622/ricco/) on 2018-07-25**:
thanks. this is what I was looking for.